# connection to server /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 failed Connection refused Is the server running locally and accepting connections on socket?

Tags: ubuntu, psql

psql: error: connection to the server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

I had PostgreSQL working fine on Ubuntu, but I can't connect anymore to the database. I'm getting this error when running the command `psql -d dbName -U user` `psql: error: connection to the server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

Comment: In my postgresql.conf I have `listen_addresses = '*'` `unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'`
In pg_hba.conf I have ```# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all               0.0.0.0/0    md5```